# Determining the lowest ever value of several ever changing cells

Tags: libreoffice

I have a row of three cells with constantly changing values. Cell 4 I wish to display the lowest value ever achieved by any one of the 3 cells. By definition the value of cell 4 can only go down, not up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a simple way to achieve this using only Calc built in functions, but attach an event macro would do the trick.

Say your 3 cells are: B1, B2, B3

Then in B4 `=min(B1:B3)`

Then put an event trigger on B4 using a code similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72064985/in-libreoffice-calc-how-do-i-change-through-libreoffice-basic-the-value-of-a-ce/72197419#72197419).

The trigger code in `Modify_modified` should check if B4 is smaller than B5. If it is, then write the new min value in B5.

Comment: That level of coding is beyond my comprehension but I'm obliged for your response.

Comment: As mentioned in many places, Stack Overflow is not supposed to be code writing service. I had already done too much in the mentioned post. That post and my suggestion in this post should have enough to get someone with coding knowledge to  solving your problem.